# How to render <style> tag using DOMPurify

Tags: javascript, dompurify

In our application for a very specific scenario (at only one place)  we need to bypass the  tag and render it on the DOM using DOMPurify.

```
var htmlScript = "<style>*{color: red}</style>"; // something like this
var clean = dompurify.sanitize(htmlScript, { ADD_TAGS: ['style']});
return clean;
```

Does anyone know how to achieve it ?

Comment: Rather than injecting inline-styles, which CSP will general flag as highly suspect and may even outright forbid, why not have a stylesheet with classes that you can toggle on the elements that need those styles applied, instead?

Comment: This is how we are receiving the data that we are not supposed to change. Do you know any solution ?

Comment: Not without additional details: the code you're showing generates a string, so right now the answer is "the way you would inject pure HTML into a DOM", entirely independent of dompurify - and there are plenty of pages on the web, and answers SO, that explain how to turn "some HTML code" into real elements on your page/webview or nodes in an actual DOM. So it might be worth considering that this might not be a dompurify question at all, and editing it to only focus on what you really need (or even deleting it if it's really is just about turning HTML into live elements)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that with [these 3 options](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#can-i-configure-dompurify): `FORCE_BODY`, `ALLOWED_TAGS`, and `ALLOWED_ATTR`.

Example:

```
outHtml = domPurify.sanitize(outHtml, {
    FORCE_BODY: true,
    ALLOWED_ATTR: ['style', 'class', 'type', 'href', 'rel'],
    // must add these tag manually if use this option.
    ALLOWED_TAGS: [
      'link',
      'figure',
      'table',
      'caption',
      'thead',
      'tr',
      'th',
      'tbody',
      'td',
    ],
  });
```